# Laravel firstOrCreate duplicates

Tags: php, laravel

Have not been able to find an answer on this one. I have a `Many-to-Many` relation between `Expense` and `Tag`. I have a simple form where I can enter some tags, seperated with a comma. In my `store` method I do the following:

```
foreach(explode(",", $request->tags) as $tag)
{
    $tags[] = auth()->user()->tags()->firstOrCreate(['name' => $tag])->id;
}
```

This will create the tags that do not exist, and returns an array of the `tag_ids` so I can sync it with my `Expense`.

```
$expense->tags()->sync($tags); // Note, $expense is also created in my store method, ofcourse
```

But my issue is, it is creating duplicates, and I cannot figure out why. There isn't much to find online unfortunately.

Comment: What's the relationship between user and tags?  Seems like you could be getting duplicate names because they exist under different users.

Comment: A user hasMany Tags. And the duplicates occur for one user only, me :)

Comment: Setup migrations to not allow duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It seems there were either white spaces before, or after the name of the tag. So I need to remove those before inserting.

Comment: make sure to mark this as your answer if this works.

Comment: I will, just waiting until I can mark it, since it's my own answer it takes a few days :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a mistake in setting up the migrations and not doing validations correctly.

1) In your migrations you should be able to set it so a name for a tag is only allowed to be entered once in the table.

2) You should check or create form validation. Now since you're either selecting or creating a record it will be a little trickery, but it should certainly be achievable.

Next to that as a little hint, make sure to remove any whitespaces and lowercase the tags. This will also disallow 2 of the same tags 1 having an uppercase and the other being fully lowercased.